# CORBA.MARSHAL: Unable to read value from underlying bridge : initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible vmcid

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, corba

I am running my Java EE project on IBM WebSphere 8.5 using JDK 1.7.1 64 bits.

When I perform a remote call to an EJB from my Swing client (JDK 1.8 Oracle 64 bits), the following exception is thrown. I have tried to use different JDKs in the client (even with the server JDK), the result has always been the same:

```
2019-01-30 11:49:20 ERROR OpMyProject:261 - CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f89a No; nested exception is:
   org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:
   >> SERVER (id=4ee74d90, host=myhost.local) TRACE START:
   >>    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Unable to read value from underlying bridge : initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 89A  completed: No
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.IDRReader.read_value(IDRReader.java:2054)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.EncoderInputStream.read_value(EncoderInputStream.java:963)
   >>     at org.myproject.model.ejb._EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie.havePermission(_EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie.java:100)
   >>     at org.myproject.model.ejb._EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie.java)
   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:628)
   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:510)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:607)
   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1583)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3166)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3030)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.WorkQueueElement.dispatch(WorkQueueElement.java:174)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.filter.GiopFilterChain.processMessage(GiopFilterChain.java:203)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.handleRequest(PooledThread.java:81)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:102)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
   >> SERVER (id=4ee74d90, host=myhost.local) TRACE END.
  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 89A  completed: No
java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f89a No; nested exception is:
   org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:
   >> SERVER (id=4ee74d90, host=myhost.local) TRACE START:
   >>    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Unable to read value from underlying bridge : initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 89A  completed: No
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.IDRReader.read_value(IDRReader.java:2054)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.EncoderInputStream.read_value(EncoderInputStream.java:963)
   >>     at org.myproject.model.ejb._EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie.havePermission(_EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie.java:100)
   >>     at org.myproject.model.ejb._EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemote0SLMyProjectBean_e0f6ccfa_Tie.java)
   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:628)
   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:510)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:607)
   >>     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1583)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3166)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3030)
   >>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.WorkQueueElement.dispatch(WorkQueueElement.java:174)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.filter.GiopFilterChain.processMessage(GiopFilterChain.java:203)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.handleRequest(PooledThread.java:81)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:102)
   >>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
   >> SERVER (id=4ee74d90, host=myhost.local) TRACE END.
  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 89A  completed: No
   at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.UtilDelegateImpl.mapSystemException(UtilDelegateImpl.java:284)
   at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:78)
   at org.myproject.model.ejb._MyProjectBeanRemote_Stub.havePermission(_MyProjectBeanRemote_Stub.java:1)
   at org.myproject.op.OpMyProject.havePermission(OpMyProject.java:258)
   at org.myproject.ui.FMyProject.init(FMyProject.java:137)
   at org.myproject.ui.FMyProject.<init>(FMyProject.java:78)
   at org.myproject.ui.MyProject.iniciaAplicacionVisual(MyProject.java:218)
   at org.myproject.ui.MyProject.access$100(MyProject.java:31)
   at org.myproject.ui.MyProject$1.loginSucceeded(MyProject.java:92)
   at org.jdesktop.swingx.auth.LoginService.fireLoginSucceeded(LoginService.java:247)
   at org.jdesktop.swingx.auth.LoginService$1$2.run(LoginService.java:153)
   at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone had to face this issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue these days. It seems that it is a problem with the firewall. Many CORBA.MARSHAL exceptions occur due to a failing ORB meta callback:

- Callback is a separate request sent (usually) from the server back to the client which must be completed before the original incoming request can be processed).
- Looking closely at the stack above we see an ORB meta callback being attempted (likely from server back to the client):

You can use a parameter to indicate to avoid this situation.

```
com.ibm.CORBA.enableClientCallbacks=true
```

Source:
[IBM Developer Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/202295/orgomgcorbamarshal-unable-to-read-value-from-under.html)

I hope this may help you.

Comment: I cannot modify my firewall rules, but setting that property as a JVM parameter solved my issue. Thanks again :-)